# Does something like UglifyJS exist for whole web projects?

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications

I'm looking for a tool that minifies/compresses/uglifies my whole project, HTML, CSS and JS. I'm thinking stuff like give all the `class` and `id` attributes single letter names and then sync that over to my scripts and styles etc. Ideally I can run this once for my whole compiled site just before it goes up on the server.

Comment: But why? It seems like an obvious thing to use descriptive `class` and `id` attributes for development, and then serve the shortest names possible...

Comment: For HTML compression you can check HTMLcompressor but it may not be useful. It can only tri white space & strings never get compressed.So if you take a look html attribute values will never compress.So with CSS file.They only remove white space

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compress HTML, but you can compress JS & CSS 
Some available compressors are

```
1 Yui compressor
2.Google Closure Compiler
3 JSmin
4 Packer
5.Dojo ShrinkSafe
```